# HTML-таблица не изменяется

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Нужна была валидная верстка, я ее сделал, исправил все ошибки, как с HTML, так и с CSS. Загвоздка в том, что теперь таблица не изменяется вообще, не реагирует ни на один способ манипуляций.

Вот собственно таблица

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<div id="data">
    <table id="table">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="data_1 data_2">
                <img src="images/eye.png" alt="eye" />
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_3">
                <img src="images/dialog.png" alt="dialog" />
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_4">
                <img src="images/catalog.png" alt="catalog" />
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_5">
                <img src="images/catalog1.png" alt="catalog1" />
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_6">
                <img src="images/rever.png" alt="rever" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="data_1 data_0">
                <a href="#" class="laws">Законопроекты</a>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_2">
                <p class="eye">6.2 K</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_3">
                <p class="eye">48 K</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_4">
                <p class="eye">112</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_5">
                <p class="eye">400</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_6">
                <p class="eye">15:25 | 24.04.2012</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="test">
            <td class="data_1 data_0">
                <a href="#" class="laws">Проекты постановления Правительства</a>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_2">
                <p class="eye">2.1 K</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_3">
                <p class="eye">21 K</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_4">
                <p class="eye">25</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_5">
                <p class="eye">207</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_6">
                <p class="eye">16:04 | 24.04.2012</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="test">
            <td class="data_1 data_0">
                <a href="#" class="laws">Проекты технических Регламентов</a>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_2">
                <p class="eye">3.0 K</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_3">
                <p class="eye">12 K</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_4">
                <p class="eye">145</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_5">
                <p class="eye">358</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_6">
                <p class="eye">15:05 | 24.04.2012</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="test">
            <td class="data_1 data_0">
                <a href="#" class="laws">Проекты Таможенного Союза</a>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_2">
                <p class="eye">5.6 K</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_3">
                <p class="eye">42 K</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_4">
                <p class="eye">68</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_5">
                <p class="eye">116</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_6">
                <p class="eye">16:24 | 24.04.2012</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="test">
            <td class="data_1 data_0">
                <a href="#" class="laws">Планы мероприятий</a>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_2">
                <p class="eye">0.6 K</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_3">
                <p class="eye">8 K</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_4">
                <p class="eye">211</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_5">
                <p class="eye">502</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_6">
                <p class="eye">12:48 | 24.04.2012</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="test">
            <td class="data_1 data_0">
                <a href="#" class="laws">Тарифыне и не тарифные меры регулирования</a>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_2">
                <p class="eye">1.5 K</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_3">
                <p class="eye">15 K</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_4">
                <p class="eye">13</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_5">
                <p class="eye">45</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_6">
                <p class="eye">13:00 | 24.04.2012</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="test">
            <td class="data_1 data_0">
                <a href="#" class="laws">Приказы государственных органов</a>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_2">
                <p class="eye">2.0 K</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_3">
                <p class="eye">38 K</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_4">
                <p class="eye">12</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_5">
                <p class="eye">98</p>
            </td>
            <td class="data_1 data_6">
                <p class="eye">15:25 | 24.04.2012</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: А валидация кода, она такая)) не всегда полезная.

Comment: А как вы меняете вашу таблицу?

Comment: @gold скриншот хоть покажите что у вас меняется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С чем у вас ошибка не знаю, но:

1. В HTML5 другой DOCTYPE. Или у вас верстка не под 5?
2. Зачем каждому `p` `class`? Вы во всей таблице используете его только с этим классом и больше никак. Просто привяжите к `id` этой таблицы еще и `p` с нужным классом. Код же сократится сразу.

Собственно, вопрос, а как должна изменяться таблица? Вы не можете ее отредактировать или она у вас там как-то загадочно мигала при наведении мышкой?

Comment: Нет,до 5-ки еще не вырос )
Она у меня вытянулась и средствами CSS сокращаться не хочет.
К коду пока претензии нету ,валидный,но сокращу как совет ))

Comment: Было бы отлично увидеть сайт, на котором реализован этот код. 
Если это секрет, то советую вам установить Google Chrome, зайти на сайт и нажать F12. Там вы увидите код. Нажав на определенные его строчки, сможете увидеть и стили, которые влияют на него. Проверьте, может у вас там просто замещение какое :)

Comment: У меня FF11 + Firebug, ставлю ДОКТАЙП верстка на месте, таблица(приведенная выше) становится вытянутой, а без него все как установлено с CSS.